# iPhone : when test the app on device got this error "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTThumbsViewController"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I got this errors when build & Run to test my app on my device.
when i build & run the app on simulator there are no errors ! it works well,
Only on device the error appears

The errors :

```
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTThumbsViewController", referenced from:

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTModel", referenced from:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTThumbsViewController", referenced from:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTModel", referenced from:
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the correct Three20 headers. Most likely importing either `TTThumbsViewController` or `TTThumbsViewController` will resolve the other 2 you have listed.